# Warning: unlink(/web/htdocs/www.vhannibal.net/home/setting/): Is a directory in [...]

Tags: php, mysql, unlink

```
require("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]mysql.php");
$id = $_GET["id"];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE ID = \"$id\"");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
switch ($_GET["action"])
{
    case "update":
    if (!unlink("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]setting/$row[Filename]"))
    {
        echo "Non è stato possibile cancellare il vecchio file.";
        header("Refresh: 2.5; url=index.php");
        exit();
    }
```

The error is "Warning: unlink(/web/htdocs/www.vhannibal.net/home/setting/): Is a directory in [...] on line 43", line 43 is

```
if (!unlink("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]setting/$row[Filename]"))
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: If you do a var_dump of $row, is filename set? It could be that the mysql query is not returning a result.

Answer (score 2):

First off, you should consider going back to basics and reading up on input validation.

Ignoring the glaring mysql injection issue, `unlink()` can only be called on files. In your code here, you don't check whether `$row['Filename']` is a file or not before deleting it.

The least you could do is check whether the file exists

```
if (is_file("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]setting/{$row['Filename']}")) {
  //delete code
}
```

Answer (score 1):

$row[Filename] is not having any data in it or its empty string.

Comment: you can still use `$row[Filename]` that is not the problem try it by yourself and you will surprised

Comment: @Shakti : check my first line. I am not saying you must use $row['Filename'];, i m saying you should use $row['Filename'];

Comment: **in fact, quotes has nothing to do with array indexes**

Comment: -1 That is just a guess only not an answer it should or must be a comment

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel : but generally we use quote in array indexing. isn't it?

Comment: @Gaurav nope, we don't. array key doesn't require any special syntax (beside square brackets, of course). are you sure you want to use quotes for this statement: $array[$key]?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: not in $array[$key] but how about in $array['aneKey']?

Comment: @Guarav: Irrelevant. It's not `$array[aneKey]` but `"$array[aneKey]"`. BIG difference.

Comment: why not in $array[$key]? you said `'we use quote in array indexing'`, but why don't you want to use quotes with this index?

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal : Thanks for comment. But Still i am confused with it. Do you have any link for that.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: in $array[$key] $key is variable, which will be having any value. but if I use any hardcore string as index, then I should use it or not?

Comment: If I say `if (!unlink("$_SERVER[DOCUMENT_ROOT]setting/'".$row['Filename']."'"))` then is it correct?

Comment: what's so special with "hardcore strings" being array keys? Would you ask if it's not `$row[Filename]` but `echo filename` or `$var = trim(filename)`?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Thanks for all.

Comment: so, it's **strings** you're talking about, not array keys :) Sure, quotes are required to distinguish strings from everything else. As for your question see "More examples..." section here: http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php

Comment: @Guarav: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing example #8

Answer (score 0):

As there is still no right answer I have to write it myself.

As Gaurav pointed it out, you are not checking if mysql query returned any data
thus, your code should be (however, I'd write strings more usual way):

```
require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/mysql.php");
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Setting WHERE ID = ".intval($_GET["id"]);
$res = mysql_query() or trigger_error(mysql_error().$sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

if ($row) // <-- here it is!
{
    switch ($_GET["action"])
    {
        case "update":
        if (!unlink($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."setting/".$row['Filename']))
        {
            echo "Non è stato possibile cancellare il vecchio file.";
            header("Refresh: 2.5; url=index.php");
            exit();
        }
    }
}
```